# Can you have a plugin architecture in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, plugins

Is it possible to load external "web-parts" in an ASP.NET website? I would like to make stand-alone dll's containing a User-Control or Page to include in a main site. Like a plug-in architecture for websites.

The only examples I can seem to find bind the user control to the main project, you need to have a "hard" reference to the control.

What I would like is to define a shared interface which the plugins can implement, and the website can load and display.

Comment: You can definitely have a DLL that contains a bunch of user controls. And your user controls can of course implement an interface of your choice. However, you seem to want more than that--but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: User Controls can't seem to be loaded "on-demand", like a plugin. You would need to include a reference in the host website. I would like to be able to load any .dll that implements my interface, without changes in the host website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discussion over here about compiling `UserControl`s into dlls

[ASP.NET UserControl class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765867/asp-net-usercontrol-class-library/1765900#1765900)

For something like what you are describing, I would highly recommend [creating custom server controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f%28VS.80%29.aspx). You could provide an abstract base class for all plug ins.

```
public abstract class PluginBase : WebControl {

}
```

Then you could search a directory for assemblies and search each assembly for anything deriving from that type.

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] assemblies = di.GetFiles("*.dll");
    foreach (var assembly in assemblies) {
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly.FullName);
        foreach (Type type in a.GetTypes()) {
            if (type.BaseType == typeof(PluginBase)) {                     
                //load plugin
            }
        } 
    }
```

You can also register your plug ins in your web.config by providing a config section like the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx)

Comment: That seems like a nice solution. Would you have to build up the WebControl completely in code, or is there the possibility to use the templating engine?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins can implement your interface. Interface may define one method. This method takes necessary general inputs to plugin's context. plugin's responsibility will be to return html markup which can be placed on the final output page. This way you can widegtize this but compromise Page lifecycle and postback features becuase the page has no idea what is returned by the plugin.

Comment: Would I also lose the postback-features if the interface implements the WebControl like Bob suggests?

Comment: Yes, you will lose postback features. Just to give you an idea UserControls is inbuilt plugin mechanism provided by asp.net. UserControl derives from System.Web.UI.Page which makes it postback capable. I recommend rather than reinventing the wheel you should try to specialize UserControls by making your own UserControl base class and make it available to plugin developers. It can be so special that it may expose methods and props that are coupled to your application architecture and core business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have an Infrastructure which capable to load decoupled Modules.(Inversion of control, or IoC )

read more about WCSF
Web Client Software Factory
**www.codeplex.com/websf**

if you want nice sample code about design web application with modular approach please download [Cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/)

> Cuyahoga is an open source .NET web
>   site framework. It provides content
>   management capabilities and has a
>   modular approach

after all  read the ASP.NET 3.5 Social Networking
very nice book.

> Create a full-featured, enterprise-grade social network using
>   ASP.NET 3.5
>    Learn key new ASP.NET topics in a practical, hands-on way: LINQ, AJAX,
>   C# 3.0, n-tier architectures, and MVC
>    **Build friends lists, messaging systems, user profiles, blogs, message
>   boards, groups, and more**
>    Rich with example code, clear explanations, interesting examples,
>   and practical advice – a truly
>   hands-on book for ASP.NET developers

**www.packtpub.com/expert-guide-for-social-networking-with-asp-.net-3.5/book**

the author show us how to apply design patterns to real world web applications.
all the modules that highlighted with Bold Font are developed with IoC Pattern with use of **StructureMap**

This Book Also has very nice sample code that you can download from Packt Publishing website.